# Progress bar does not show without text in localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Implemented a progress bar using HTML/CSS & JQuery. So when i scroll down the page a blue bar appears at the top. This does not appear.

show.html

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.progress {
  position: fixed;
  top:  0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #7fdbff;
}
```

scroll.js

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  var pixelsFromTop = $(document).scrollTop()

  if (pixelsFromTop < 600) {
    $('section').css('background-color', '#fff0f0')
  } else if (pixelsFromTop < 1200) {
    $('section').css('background-color', '#F8D800')
  } else if (pixelsFromTop < 1600) {
    $('section').css('background-color', '#F6FFFF') 
  } else {
    $('section').css('background-color', '#cdccc7')
  }

  var documentHeight = $(document).height()
  var windowHeight = $(window).height()
  var difference = documentHeight - windowHeight
  var percentage = 100 * pixelsFromTop / difference

  $('.bar').css('width', percentage + '%')

})
```

But when i add text in the progress div the bar appears

e.g

show

i get the following

[image]

but want it to work without the text

inspect element the width increases

[image]

html code

```
<section class="day">
    <h1><%= "To make #{number_to_currency @product.revenue}" %></h1>
     <p><%= "You need to make #{number_to_currency @product.monthly_amount} a month" %><br/>
        <%= "You need to make #{number_to_currency @product.daily_amount} a day" %>
    </p>
    <br/>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</section>


<section class="people"> 

    <h1>If you create & sell a product</h1>
        <p><%= "To make #{@product.revenue } 10,000 people to buy a
        #{number_to_currency @product.create_and_sell_product_10000} product" %><br/>

        <%= "To make #{@product.revenue } 5,000 people to buy a
        #{number_to_currency @product.create_and_sell_product_5000} product" %><br/>

        <%= "To make #{@product.revenue } 2,000 people to buy a
        #{number_to_currency @product.create_and_sell_product_2000} product" %><br/>

        <%= "To make #{@product.revenue } 1,000 people to buy a
     #{number_to_currency @product.create_and_sell_product_1000} product" %><br/>

        <%= "To make #{@product.revenue } 100 people to buy a
     #{number_to_currency @product.create_and_sell_product_100} product" %>
    </p>
</section>
```

Comment: @Neil it works fine in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/8ww8q3yu/), can you use this and highlight the issue?

Comment: Yes. tried this in fiddle & it works fine! When I try on localhost it doesn't. Only works if i add text?  Strange!

Comment: This does not appear? Clear up your question.

Comment: @Neil I tried the code in local server, the progess bar didn't work as you said, you need to add the css `html, body{height:100%;width:100%}` and presto it works just like the JS fiddle.

Comment: tried again but makes no difference

Comment: @Neil I am assuming that you want the progress bar to be full when there is no content, that is the only thing we have missed so just change the css for bar to `.bar{position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #7fdbff;}`

Comment: I want the progress bar to empty at the start, when the user scrolls down to see the content the progress bar to move across the page

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me. i just copied your code into a snippet and added the style `body{min-height: 1000;}` to your css. it's working just fine .

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
      var pixelsFromTop = $(document).scrollTop()

      if (pixelsFromTop < 600) {
        $('section').css('background-color', '#fff0f0')
      } else if (pixelsFromTop < 1200) {
        $('section').css('background-color', '#F8D800')
      } else if (pixelsFromTop < 1600) {
        $('section').css('background-color', '#F6FFFF')
      } else {
        $('section').css('background-color', '#cdccc7')
      }

      var documentHeight = $(document).height()
      var windowHeight = $(window).height()
      var difference = documentHeight - windowHeight
      var percentage = 100 * pixelsFromTop / difference

      $('.bar').css('width', percentage + '%')

    })
```

```css
body{min-height: 1000px;}
      .progress {
        position: fixed;
        top:  0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .bar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: #7fdbff;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML already has a progress bar tag:

```
<progress value="22" max="100"></progress>
```

this tag has 2 attributes, you should change the "value" attribute from your code. 
It's easier to use and control from JQuery or from javascript HTML DOM.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to have some content in your html so that the script can actually work. because there is nothing to scroll if you don't have any content.**

look closely into the js you've added.

```
  var windowHeight = $(window).height()
  var difference = documentHeight - windowHeight
  var percentage = 100 * pixelsFromTop / difference

  $('.bar').css('width', percentage + '%')
```

Here you are incrementing/decrementing the percentage of your progress bar. The height of your whole document and the amount you scrolled from top of your document is used here to calculate your progress percentage.